# SQL select from 2 tables where key isn't in some rows in 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
ID       Type
---     -------
1        17    
2        18    
3        18   
10       16
```

And a second table like this

```
ID       Month
---     -------
1        Feb    
2        Feb    
3        Feb
4        Feb
```

I would like to select everything in the second table and match it up with a type in the first table. If it doesn't have a matching ID in the first table I would still like to show it.

Right now I'm doing this query

```
 select t2.id, t2.month, t1.type
 from t2, t1
 where t1.id = t2.id
```

and it is giving me this result

```
ID   MONTH  TYPE
1    Feb     17
2    Feb     18
3    Feb     18
```

But what I would like is this result

```
ID   MONTH  TYPE
1    Feb     17
2    Feb     18
3    Feb     18
4    Feb     0
```

How can I write an SQL statement this will give me the above result?

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c90f5/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a `LEFT JOIN` -- I've also used `COALESCE` to return 0 for the Type -- you could also use `IFNULL`:

```
SELECTt2.id, t2.month,  COALESCE(t1.type,0) type
FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c90f5/2)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an outer join, which gives you all rows of one table and those values of the other table that join. Like this:

```
select t2.id, t2.month, t1.type
from t2 left outer join t1
on t1.id = t2.id
```

But the values for type are missing for the 4th of feb, so they are null.

If this is what you need, you have to map null to 0 in the field list, but I wouldn't recommend that, because it's simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.month, t2.type
FROM t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN t1
    ON t1.id = t2.id 
UNION(
SELECT t2.id, t2.month, '0' AS type
FROM t2
EXCEPT
SELECT t2.id, t2.month, '0' AS type
FROM t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN t1
    ON t1.id = t2.id )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make make a `LEFT JOIN` and use a `IFNULL`

```
SELECT table2.id, table2.month, IFNULL(table1.type, 0) as type FROM t2 as table2 LEFT JOIN t1 table1 ON table2.id = table1.id
```